# Why don't shares of photos from my page to a group show when the group post is re-shared?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups, facebook-timeline

When I post to a photo (normally via Cinch Share) to a Facebook page I manage, I normally manually share that to another Facebook group I admin.

It shows up fine in the group. However, if someone else then shares from the group post, the photo doesn't show in their time line. Just a Show Attachment with a link to the group's post.

Like this:

[image: Person Shared your Post Photo]

If you drill into the `Show Attachment` link you don't get much more:

[image]

Basically a link to the photo I posted, but not the photo or the accompanying text.

Posting it directly to the group seems to share properly on others timelines.

The pattern is:

1. Photo posted to page - photo and text shows up on page
2. Shared from page to group - photo and text shows up on group
3. Re-shared from group - no photo or text show up in the second share (either in group or in personal timelines)

What am I doing wrong?

I'd like to only post it once in the page because I get Insights off the page that we don't get off of the group.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. I didn't understand what you wan to do exactly. :(

Comment: I added some anonymised screen shots to make the question clearer

Answer (score -1):

Facebook doesn't allow sharing *from* closed or secret groups. Anyone who wants to share a photo/post from your Page needs to go to your Page and share from there.

Comment: It's definitely a Public Group. And sharing other posts from that group seem to work as expected (the photo and text show up)..